# Display element only if another element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about hiding a div and only displaying it if another div existed on a page? I'm guessing jquery or js would be the way to go....

```
<style type="text/css">
.always-here {
   display:none;
}
</style>

<div class="im-here">This div exists on this particular page!</div>
<div class="always-here">This div is always here but has the style 
display: none unless a div with the class "im-here" exists.</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your current current html you can do

```
.always-here {
   display:none;
}
.im-here ~ .always-here{
   display:block;
}
```

this will only work if `.always-here` and `.im-here` are siblings and `.im-here` comes before.

http://jsfiddle.net/BKYSV/ - `.im-here` present
http://jsfiddle.net/BKYSV/1/ - `.im-here` absent

Comment: Wow, had no idea this could be solved with CSS. Is this method cross browser compatible?

Comment: @Heather see http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors , https://www.google.tt/search?q=general+sibling+selector&oq=general+sibling+selector&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6681j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fp=828651ec3b51e1b8&q=css+general+sibling+selector+browser+support

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".im-here").length > 0)
    {
        $(".always-here").show();
    }
});
```

here is the code
 [Click Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/62NbY/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($(".im-here").length)
$(".always-here").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Musa's solution works on but your `.always-here` element MUST be after the `.im-here` element.
A more comprehensive way to achieve your goal is to use `:has()` functionality:

```
.always-here {
   display: none;
}
.always-here:has(+ .im-here) {
  display: block;
}
```